# Publish an MVC application with a web.config for each production environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, web-deployment, msdeploy, web-config-transform

I have an MVC application with a **Dev**, **Staging**, and **Production** environment. Dev and Staging are essentially the same thing (same VM, IIS, DB etc.); however, Production is hosted on 4 VMs behind a load balancer. Each VM has it's own DB. For example, the instance deployed to VM1 communicates with the PROD1 DB, VM2->PROD2, etc.

For deployment to Dev and Staging, I do a simple File System deployment from VS2013 to the VM using Debug/Release web.config transforms. For Production deployments, a SysAdmin will copy the bits deployed and tested in Staging to each Production VM. This is to ensure that what was tested and verified by QA in Staging is what we promote to Production -- I don't want to do another build between Staging and Production. Because of this, our SysAdmin is responsible for (with DevOps guidance) editing each web.config between Staging and Production. This basically consists of changing `connectionString` values from `"Data Source=STAGINGDB"` to `"Data Source=PROD1"` (and PROD2, PROD3, PROD4).

What I ultimately want is when I publish to Staging, I want to deploy my web.config using standard Release web.config transform; however, alongside this file I want to also create and drop 4 additional files (web.config.PROD1, .PROD2, etc.). This will allow us to create scripts which ignore the existing web.config (with Staging settings) and copy/rename the appropriate .PROD config.

I am able to (sort of) achieve this with MSBuild:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build">
    ...
    <Target Name="Build">
        <TransformXml Source="Web.config" Transform="Web.PROD1.config" Destination="Web.config.PROD1" />
        <TransformXml Source="Web.config" Transform="Web.PROD2.config" Destination="Web.config.PROD2" />
        ...
    </Target>
</Project>
```

My main issue with this approach is that I have to create 4 essentially redundant solution configurations to wire up to the Transform. Every setting is the same except the DB `connectionString`. Seems like there should be a more efficient way.

Can I execute individual transforms without solution configurations by simply calling the appropriate transform via MSBuild, like:

```
<add name="connectionString" connectionString="PROD1" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
```

Should I be using another process altogether? I'd rather not use a 3rd party nuget solution if I can stay way from it. Should I be using a .wpp.targets file? XmlPoke?

## My desired workflow

1. Right-click my MVC app and choose "Publish" (File System)
2. Let the Release transforms do their thing and generate the web.config. I have basic configurations. Debug = Dev, Release = Staging.

[image: WebConfigs]

3. Add a custom step that generates 4 additional web.config files
4. Package everything up, and publish to the Staging server, so I see this on the VM:

[image: Publish]

Everything I've read leads me to believe that I should be writing custom MSBuild steps, but I don't know what I should be doing (or how). Here's some pseudo-code:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build">
    ...
    <Target Name="Build">
        <TransformXml Source="Web.config" Transform="[Do-Basic-Transform-On-Conection-String]" Destination="Web.config.PROD1" />
        <TransformXml Source="Web.config" Transform="[Do-Basic-Transform-On-Conection-String]" Destination="Web.config.PROD2" />
        <IncludeFilesInPublish>
            <FileToInclude>Web.config.PROD1</FileToInclude>
            <FileToInclude>Web.config.PROD2</FileToInclude>
        </IncludeFilesInPublish>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

- Can I `[Do-Basic-Transform-On-Connection-String]` inline here without a solution configuration? I'll only be changing 2 `connectionString` values. If I need to create a solution config, that's fine... I just don't think it's totally necessary especially if I can do it inline. Maybe I'm wrong?
- How do I accomplish the `<IncludeFilesInPublish>` bit so that whatever I do get's packaged up during the Publish, so my Staging deployment has my release candidate code and web.configs ready for promotions.

Comment: Solution configurations seem pretty cheap to me. Is there any particular reason you would rather not have the extra configurations (other than redundancy)? That being said, I don't think you need a solution configuration to run the transform. Did you try just adding the web.prodX.config files without an associated solution configuration and using your existing msbuild solution?

Comment: @rusmus yes, basically just redundancy and clutter. I don't think you can add a web.prodX.config file without the corresponding sln configuration (unless I'm missing something). I'm not necessarily opposed to the redundant configurations, but I still don't know how to execute all 4 (in addition to the standard Release) and package those up during a single Publish.

Comment: We have solved this with two types of files. One is Environment Definition file, which contains all key-value mappings of specific deployment enviornment say prod1,prod2 etc. and our web.config files will only have keys representing connectiongstring etc. variables. e.g. <ConnectionString name="abc" value="$$env.def.key$$"/>. At the time of deployment, our Jenkins script replaces keys like $$env.def.key$$ with actual prod1 or prod2 values. This helps us to keep our code seperate from enviornment specific things as well as helps to maintain security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the extra transform files to your solution without adding a new solution configuration, and run the transform as in your own example (except for the target. 'Build' didn't work for me):

```
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build">
    ...
    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
        <TransformXml Source="Web.config" Transform="Web.PROD1.config" Destination="Web.config.PROD1" />
        <TransformXml Source="Web.config" Transform="Web.PROD2.config" Destination="Web.config.PROD2" />
        ...
    </Target>
</Project>
```

If you are only changing a connectionstring, your transform file will be pretty minimal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyDB" 
        connectionString="Data Source=PROD1SQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyReleaseDB;Integrated Security=True" 
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

After adding the above, and compiling, you will need to add the newly generated Web.config.PRODX files to your solution. After adding them, you simply open properties for each file and ensure that their compile action is set to 'Content'. This will mean that they are included in your deployments.

As the web.PRODX.config transform files are not part of a solution configuration, you could stick them in a folder to reduce clutter.

Comment: I had no idea you could specify a Transform source without a corresponding solution configuration. This also works for my log4net.config as well. This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

I think your question is twofold: 1) *how do I pass environment variables or parameters (i.e. PROD1) into my xdt transformation file so I only have to use one transformation file?* and 2) *how do I get MSBuild to iterate over a set of known named items to produce outputs distinguished by each item in this set?*

For the first part, the only reason why I assert you might be asking this is because you said "I have to create 4 essentially redundant solution configurations to wire up to the Transform", so if your transform took "PROD1" as a parameter you could ideally just use one transform. But I'm not sure that you can do this without creating your own XmlTransform task. The xdt transformation tooling is really limited. But the nice thing about MSBuild is that it's flexible enough that you could theoretically come up with your own transformation task that extends/subclasses or behaves like the one out of the box.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;
using Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks;

namespace Thanks.IllWriteMyOwnTasks
{
    public class MyCustomTransformXml : TransformXml // no idea if you can do this
    {
        public override bool Execute()
        {
            // do stuff here, 
            // maybe declare parameters that you can pass down to base.Execute()
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

..

```
<!--<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />-->
<UsingTask TaskName="MyCustomTransformXml" AssemblyFile="Thanks.IllWriteMyOwnTasks.dll" />
```

For the second part, I think you can use ItemGroup.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MyEnvironments Include="PROD1" />
    <MyEnvironments Include="PROD2" />
    <MyEnvironments Include="PROD3" />
    <MyEnvironments Include="PROD4" />
</ItemGroup>  
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <TransformXml Source="Web.config" 
                  Transform="Web.%(MyEnvironments.Identity).config" 
                  Destination="Web.config.%(MyEnvironments.Identity)" />
</Target>
```

I haven't tested this, but I *think* based on what I see [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036748/how-do-i-perform-the-exec-task-in-a-loop-with-msbuild-itemgroups) it will automatically repeat the same task as it iterates over `MyEnvironments` in this example.

Comment: I think you're on the right track. I'm still guessing with OP intent, but you seem to have a handle on the right direction.