# How do I loop in MSBuild Target file with different files?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have below MSBuild Target file setup. This works fine with one JSON file.

```
<Target Name="dev" 
            AfterTargets="PrepareForBuild"
            BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild"
            Condition="$(Configuration) != 'Debug'">  

        <Message Text="Building Application (dev.json)" />

        <ItemGroup>
            <ScriptFile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)myscript.ps1" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
            <ScriptArgs Include="-Source &quot;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)&quot;" />
            <ScriptArgs Include="-PathToManifest &quot;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\test\dev.json&quot;" />
        </ItemGroup>

        <Exec  Command="powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File &quot;@(ScriptFile)&quot; @(ScriptArgs,' ')" 
               Condition="Exists('@(ScriptFile)')" />
        <Error Condition="!Exists('@(ScriptFile)')"
               Text="Script file: &quot;@(ScriptFile)&quot; not found. Existing dev.json incomplete!" />

    </Target>
```

I have verified a few questions here but didn't help so posting here. How do I add this in a loop so I can run the same script with different JSON files?

I have `test\dev.json` configured, and I have `test.json`, `prod.json`.

Everything stays the same but the input file needs to looping through.

I have tried a suggestion as below but still didn't work.

```
 <ItemGroup>
        <MyJsonFile Include="dev.json" />
        <MyJsonFile Include="test.json" />
        <MyJsonFile Include="prod.json" />
 </ItemGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
        <ScriptFile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)myscript.ps1" />
 </ItemGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
        <ScriptArgs Include="-Source &quot;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)&quot;" />
        <ScriptArgs Include="-PathToManifest &quot;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\test\%(MyJsonFile.Identity)&quot;" />
    </ItemGroup>
<Target Name="dev" 
            AfterTargets="PrepareForBuild"
            BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild"
            Condition="$(Configuration) != 'Debug'">  
<Exec  Command="powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File &quot;@(ScriptFile)&quot; @(ScriptArgs,' ')" 
               Condition="Exists('@(ScriptFile)')" />
        <Error Condition="!Exists('@(ScriptFile)')"
               Text="Script file: &quot;@(ScriptFile)&quot; not found. Existing dev.json incomplete!" />

    </Target>
```

I get

> Cannot validate argument on parameter  1>  'PathToManifest'.

I tried moving my ScriptArgs' ItemGroup inside Target but that gives another error

> Cannot bind parameter because parameter  1>  'PathToManifest' is
>   specified more than once. To provide multiple values to parameters
>   that can accept multiple  1>  values, use the array syntax.

Comment: probably should not put %(MyJsonFile.Identity) into another item group, but leave it specified right in the parameter you send to exec.

Comment: yes, that's right.  Removed the second ItemGroup and used Identity directly in EXEC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I loop in MSBuild Target file with different files?

You can add those different JSON files in to the `ItemGroup`, then use the MSBuild item metadata `Identity` to loop those input files, like:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <MyJsonFile Include="test.json" />
    <MyJsonFile Include="dev.json" />
    <MyJsonFile Include="prod.json" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Then use `%(MyJsonFile.Identity)` to loop those input files:

```
<ItemGroup>
        ...
        <ScriptArgs Include="-PathToManifest &quot;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\test\%(MyJsonFile.Identity)&quot;" />

</ItemGroup>
```

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036748/how-do-i-perform-the-exec-task-in-a-loop-with-msbuild-itemgroups) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Should I move my JSON Files `<ItemGroup>` and ScriptArgs' `<ItemGroup>` outside (above) of `<Target>` so my `<exec` only remains inside my `<Target>`?  Did I understand correct?

Comment: I have tried the logic on that link but it's not picking up the name in ItemGroup.  I get below error on build `PathToManifest "BuildManifest\%(MyJsonFile.Identity)"" exited with code 1`

Comment: You don't have to move your <ItemGroup> if you don't want to. It just has to be defined BEFORE the exec command.

Comment: I solved it by removing my second `ItemGroup` and directly using my scripts inside `exec`.  Thanks